# How to one-line this "expect" command?

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to one-line this

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_dsa.pub root@testip
expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?"
send -- "yes\r"
expect eof
```

which I would assume should be

```
/usr/bin/expect -c 'expect "\n" { eval spawn ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_dsa.pub root@testip; expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?"; send -- "yes\r" }'
```

but it is not.

Can anyone see how it should be?

Comment: As an aside, this totally defeats the security measures provided by `ssh`.  Are you sure you don't want `rsh`?

Comment: You will still need to type in your password, unless you are adding a second key.

Comment: Brian: it doesn't "totally" defeat the security.  Defeating the MitM check isn't the same as using an unencrypted connection.  It's plausible to have an environment where host IPs regenerate keys (newly spawned EC2 instances, for example) in a way that is difficult to manage.  You would still want to connect to that host securely.

Comment: But back to expect: why exactly do you want to "one line" this in the first place?  What's the value there?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you will not need it anymore, but it should be like this:

```
/usr/bin/expect -c 'spawn ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_dsa.pub root@testip ; expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" ; send -- "yes\r" ; expect eof'
```